# Add 'ssbu' tag synonym to 'super-smash-bros-ultimate`

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don't have 5 score in the category yet, but this seems pretty obvious.

- Smash Bros on the N64 is often just called `smash 64`
- Smash Bros. Melee is often called `ssbm` or `melee`
- Smash Bros. Brawl is often called `ssbb` or `brawl`
- Smash Bros. for 3DS/WiiU is often called `ssb4`

Super Smash Bros. Ultimate should have a synonym of at least `ssbu`.

Comment: Those other shortened names may not be the best examples to make your case here, because none of them currently exist as tags or synonyms either.

Comment: @murgatroid99 By default you need a minimum of 5 votes on a tag to make changes -- this can make it especially diffcult when there is a lack of questions on older tags to allow for synonym addition

Comment: Google seems to give relevant results when searching those acronyms, so given some community support for this I'd be happy to add all the acronyms as synonyms of their respective game tags